# Error on show a tutorial dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I'm trying to do a tutorial for the first time that a person open the app. I'm getting the next error, and I don't know why... :(

I call the method on the on create function

On create

```
// Show tutorial if is first time.
        tutorial();
```

Method tutorial

```
public void tutorial(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        //boolean firstTime = preferences.getBoolean("FirstTime", false);
        boolean firstTime = false; //For test purposes

        if (!firstTime) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);

            // Disable title.
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            // Set dialog content layout.
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_tutorial);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", true);
            editor.commit();

            final View top_layout = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
            final View tutorial0 = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_0);
            final View tutorial1 = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_1);
            final View tutorial2 = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_2);
            final View tutorial3 = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_3);
            final View tutorial4 = (View)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_4);

            tutorial0.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    tutorial0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tutorial1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            tutorial1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    tutorial1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tutorial2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            tutorial2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    tutorial2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tutorial3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            tutorial3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    tutorial3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tutorial4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            tutorial4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Error on logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{victor.martin.world/victor.martin.world.ui.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
        at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:467)
        at victor.martin.world.ui.HomeActivity.tutorial(HomeActivity.java:83)
        at victor.martin.world.ui.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
        ... 26 more
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
```

This is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--Below is the transparent layout positioned at startup -->
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="1.0"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_1"
            android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_2"
            android:visibility="gone"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_3"
            android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_4"
            android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What's line 62 of the XML?

Comment: Maybe disable title after setcontentview call. Other problem is outof memory. Could you post your graphical layout image? Bacause I coundln't understand your layout design. Outofmemory = Bitmap = ImageView.Drawable

Comment: In andriodManifest file's application tag write following attribute.
android:largeHeap = "true"

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya this is true only for API Level 11+

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a too big image in your `@drawable/tutorial_4` which is causing you an OutOfMemoryError.

Trying using a smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this problem is due to the Out of memory exception..try to take low memory images to avoid this type exception